# Select full column in Google Sheets by [@column]

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

In Microsoft Excel I know I can select a row by:

- Inserting a table (table name "Table1") with header
- Select column by = Table1[@ColumnName]

[image]

How can I do this in Google Sheets?

Comment: Take a look at the QUERY() function and use it together with Address() and Match()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you use named ranges.

For instance:

1.) Select all of Column A by clicking on the "A" at the top of that column.

2.) Select **Data > Named ranges**.

3.) Enter a descriptive name (e.g., Beers) instead of the generic name suggested and click "Done."

From that point, you can refer to that range simply by typing **Beers** in a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets doesn't support the Microsoft Excel "table" feature (i.e. From Excel menu Insert > Table).

To "select" a whole column you might use the `A:A` reference form or (as it was [previously suggested](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/163254/88163)) use a named range that points to range using an `A:A` reference.

When using `QUERY` the second parameter might make reference to column by using the column letter (use `A` instead of `A:A`) and `Col1` pattern when passing an array as the first parameter instead of a range reference.

When using `INDIRECT` you might use `R1C1` notation instead of A1 notation.